# How to add an IEEE style section in a normal latex document?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have a nice latex templete and I want to add a section in IEEE style, is there a way around this?

Comment: Sure, this can be done. To know how to do this it would be helpful to have a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows which code your nice latex template uses.

Comment: Why don't you use the existing styles from [IEEE](https://www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/templates.html), [Latex templates](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/ieee), or [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran?lang=en)?